# Selenium Chrome & Firefox Driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am struggling quite a bit to open a web browser via selenium. I literally have the drivers in C:Python312/Scripts, and also in the project folder. Both of them are giving me errors.

I can't put the driver on path. What are my options. The errors are below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 87, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilitie
```

The code is simple:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver_path = "C:/Users/E2017993/Desktop/SRC_Scrapping/pythonProject/geckodriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Firefox(driver_path)
```